# How do I specify a certain value to be changed in font colors?

Tags: fonts, conditional-statements, reportbuilder3.0, iif

I need to have a specific series of values shown in another font color, than the rest.
Example: Values from 0 to 10 =black, 11 to 20 =red, 21 to 50 =black.

I´ve tried to use this formel in so many ways, without being able to add the right formel to the string.

Any help will be highly appreciated, Thanks.

```
=IIF(Me.Value < 0, "Red", "Black")
```

Comment: Where do you use this code? Is your question related to sql `between` operator (as you have tagged it)?

Comment: I use it in Report Builder 3.0. No sorry, "between" is meant between two values - I´m sorry if I have mislead you. (My English isn´t that good)

Answer (score 0):

First - make sure that the field you're checking is a number (and not a string).  If it is not a number, then you will need to add another formula to make it a number.

If it is a number, then I suggest you use a SWITCH statement and not an IIF statement.  Without going into great detail, the use of IIF statements can cause issues.

1. I'm going to assume that your field is called "Me".  If it isn't, just substitute the field name below.
2. I'm also going to assume that your numbers are whole numbers.
3. I've given a colour for all three number groupings (not just red for 11 to 20).
4. I've also given a "catch-all" colour (blue) in case your figures can be less than zero or above 50.  (I haven't checked that this works for <0, but it does work for >50).

   =SWITCH(Fields!Me.Value >=0 and Fields!Me.Value<=10, "Black", Fields!Me.Value >=11 and Fields!Me.Value<=20, "Red", Fields!Me.Value >=21 and Fields!Me.Value<=50, "Green", True, "Blue")